# Pivot Pandas Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, pandas-melt

I'm working on this dataset:

```
# dummy data
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({None : ['Company', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC','Company', 'AAA' ],
                     None : ['Copper', 'Copper', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Gold', 'Gold'],
                     "NaN" : ['Net','Gross', 'Net','Gross', 'Net','Gross' ], 
                     "11/01/2021" : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                     "12/01/2021" : [10,11,12,13,14,15],
                     "13/01/2021" : [19,20,21,22,23,25]})
data
```

[image]

And I'm trying to get this output:

[image]

I tried with stack/melt but I wasn't able to get the data in this format.

Thanks

Comment: `data.melt(data.columns[:2])` after that rename your columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to transform the table and then use [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to format to the desired column names and row sequence:

```
(data.rename({None: 'Material', 'NaN': 'Revenue'}, axis=1)
     .melt(id_vars=['Material', 'Revenue'], var_name='Month', value_name='Value')
     .sort_values(['Material', 'Revenue'], ascending=[True, False])
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result:**

```
   Material Revenue       Month  Value
0    Copper     Net  11/01/2021      1
1    Copper     Net  12/01/2021     10
2    Copper     Net  13/01/2021     19
3    Copper   Gross  11/01/2021      2
4    Copper   Gross  12/01/2021     11
5    Copper   Gross  13/01/2021     20
6      Gold     Net  11/01/2021      5
7      Gold     Net  12/01/2021     14
8      Gold     Net  13/01/2021     23
9      Gold   Gross  11/01/2021      6
10     Gold   Gross  12/01/2021     15
11     Gold   Gross  13/01/2021     25
12     Iron     Net  11/01/2021      3
13     Iron     Net  12/01/2021     12
14     Iron     Net  13/01/2021     21
15     Iron   Gross  11/01/2021      4
16     Iron   Gross  12/01/2021     13
17     Iron   Gross  13/01/2021     22
```